# Mutt: how to safely store password?

Tags: security, mutt

My .muttrc file looks something like [this one](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/using-gmail-with-mutt-the-minimal-way/) or see below a glimpse. I am hesitant with the password. How should I store my password to use it with `mutt`?

```
set imap_user = "username@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "password"

set smtp_url = "smtp://username@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "password"
set from = "username@gmail.com"
set realname = "Your Real Name"
```

Comment: In the post you linked, I already wrote "Make sure your ~/.muttrc isn’t world-readable; it contains your password. (Alternatively, you can leave them out and mutt will prompt you for the password each time.)" :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This [tweak](http://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg36375.html) should get rid of your problem. Use gpg as suggested, or

```
set imap_pass=`getpassword email_id`
```

where you use [pwsafe](http://nsd.dyndns.org/pwsafe/) or [passwords](http://passwords.sourceforge.net/) to fetch the passwords.

Edit: If mutt is [built with IMAP support](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#toc4.11) (--enable-imap), then mutt should [prompt you for the password](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#imap%5Fpass) if you do not set it in the config file. From the manual:

> **imap_pass**
>
> Type: string Default: ""
>
> Specifies the password for your IMAP
>   account. **If unset, Mutt will prompt
>   you for your password when you invoke
>   the fetch-mail function.** Warning: you
>   should only use this option when you
>   are on a fairly secure machine,
>   because the superuser can read your
>   muttrc even if you are the only one
>   who can read the file.

Comment: +1 have mutt ask you for it.  You should only have to enter it once per session.

Comment: Also, if you run `mutt` within `tmux`, your session can last a while.

Comment: What is this function `getpassword`? I do not have it in  my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux) server. I think they are `pwsafe` or `passwords` but I should I use them? I would like to be logged into my mutt -account without password once I am logged into the server, since the password of the server is the same as the email's one.

Comment: You can use pass - https://www.passwordstore.org/ 
This tool can be used exactly the same way as described in the answer above. Passwords are stored in git repository encrypted by chosen GPG key.

Comment: Worth mentioning, backticks do not expand mutt variables so `imap_pass=\`pass ${imap_user}\`` doesn't work. But using `setenv MUTT_IMAP_USER "${imap_user}"` you can then use `imap_pass=\`pass $MUTT_IMAP_USER\``. This is particularly handy with `mutt-oauth`.

Answer (score 36):

Create a passwords file: `~/.mutt/passwords`:

```
set imap_pass="password"
set smtp_pass="password"
```

This file can be encrypted using GPG. First, create a public/private key pair:

```
$ gpg --gen-key
```

Encrypt the passwords file:

```
$ gpg -r your.email@example.com -e ~/.mutt/passwords
$ ls ~/.mutt/passwords*
/home/user/.mutt/passwords   /home/user/.mutt/passwords.gpg
$ shred ~/.mutt/passwords
$ rm ~/.mutt/passwords
```

Add to your `muttrc`:

```
source "gpg -d ~/.mutt/passwords.gpg |"
```

[via](http://pthree.org/2012/01/07/encrypted-mutt-imap-smtp-passwords/)

See also [Arch Wiki's Mutt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mutt#Passwords_management) entry.

Comment: Should the public key in the passwords file or the shell script? I think the shell script should be in .muttrc. I get after running the gpg command `gpg: masi@myuni.fi: skipped: public key not found
gpg: /u/77/masi/unix/.mutt/passwords: encryption failed: public key not found`. I did `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` but it does not seem to be the problem. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Masi, you need to have a GPG (or PGP) key, not your SSH public key. More info on GPG keys here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Creating_GPG_Keys and here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto

Comment: This is a perfect solution.  Here is my config file for anyone who needs for reference: https://github.com/shubhamchaudhary/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.muttrc

Comment: I thought this was a good solution, but then I typed `:set imap_pass` in mutt and got my password shown in cleartext.
Can this be avoided?
When mutt asks for the imap password itself, it doesn't show the caleartext password when typing :set ...

Comment: Did you create your GPG private key without password? If not `gpg -d` would require password. Why use password to encrypt a password when the goal is passwordless login...

Answer (score 7):

Why not use a wallet manager like `gnome-keyring` or `kwalletmanager` with `secret-tool`?

```
apt install gnome-keyring secret-tool
```

.[neo]muttrc:

```
source 'echo "$( pw=$( secret-tool lookup user <USERNAME> domain <DOMAIN> ); echo set imap_pass=\"$pw\"; echo set smtp_pass=\"$pw\" )" |'
```

Store your imap and smtp passwd:

```
secret-tool store --label=imap user <USERNAME> domain <DOMAIN>
```

You could choose your own label if you wanted to.

Look up your creds using a shell:

```
secret-tool lookup user <USERNAME> domain <DOMAIN>
```

Fire up your [neo]mutt, connect & login to your imap srv. Enjoy.

This solution has advantages over gpg-based ones: it integrates well and there's no additional file left layin' around.

Bonus: Use `libsecret` or directly `gnome-keyring` as a `git credential-helper` as in [git with libsecret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/10050838) and [git with gnome-keyring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528360/10050838). Both helpers need manual compilation. Yes, it's a bit awkward but it is working great.

Answer (score 3):

**To store your imap password safely in GNOME Keyring**

put

```
source ~/.muttrc-retrieve_password |
```

in your `.muttrc` with `.muttrc-retrieve_password` like

```
IMAP_PASS=$(secret-tool lookup user john_doe host mail.example)
echo "set imap_pass='$IMAP_PASS'"
```

where you need `secret-tool` to be installed via

```
$ apt-get install libsecret-tools -y
```

and the corresponding entry created like

```
$ secret-tool store --label=mutt user john_doe host mail.example service imap
```

at least for `mutt 1.9.4` @ ubuntu bionic.

---

**Update**: Instead of `source` you may directly put the line

```
set imap_pass=`secret-tool lookup --label=mutt user john_doe host mail.example`
```

into `.muttrc` (mark the backticks!)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the password from an unencrypted file.

For example, put the password into `~/secrets/mail_pass`:

```
the_secret_mail_password
```

Then

```
chmod 600 ~/secrets/mail_pass
```

In your muttrc:

```
# Read the password from a file and set it
set smtp_pass=`cat ~/secrets/mail_pass`
```

Comment: It is just much easier to `chmod 600 ~/.muttrc`.

Comment: If you keep your passwords in `~/.muttrc` you won't be able to publish it by putting it on GitLab, etc. Also, if you use OfflineIMAP it needs the password too and can read it from the external password file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ShreevatsaR's comment, I want to emphasize security. 
If password in $HOME/.muttrc, do

```
chmod go-r $HOME/.muttrc
```

However, I think this is not a secure option still. 
You should use some method which uses salt in storing passwords.