# What kind of .muttrc works on Red Hat 5.11?

Tags: mutt

This [post's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/mutt-how-to-safely-store-password) `.muttrc` works fine on all my CentOS systems, but not Red Hat 5.11. Red Hat 5.11 squawks about the:

```
set imap_user = "username@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "password"

set smtp_url = "smtp://username@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "password"
set from = "username@gmail.com"
set realname = "Your Real Name"
```

The two `smtp_` directives result in mutt complaining.

Error in /home/amr/.muttrc, line 4: smtp_url: unknown variable
Error in /home/amr/.muttrc, line 5: smtp_pass: unknown variable
source: errors in /home/amr/.muttrc
Press any key to continue...

Does anyone have a Red Hat example?

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using RHEL5 (vintage 2007)? It's pretty much fallen off the support wagon at this point.

Comment: Red Hat is still supporting it, and I do not have time to rebuild a system that's supposedly going to be replaced soon.

Comment: @thrig your question assumes that OP (and I) have control over the version and distro that we're told to use.