# Muttrc file for Gmail and Yandex

Tags: email, mutt

I have problems configuring mutt e-mail client on Lubuntu 18.04. 64 bit.

First I installed Mutt using command:

```
sudo apt install mutt
```

Everything was ok, but when I tried to add my e-mail account (Google or  Yandex mail), I can't find muttrc configuration file?

I tried to locate it:

```
su-
updatedb
locate muttrc
```

This is the output:

```
/usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d
/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/ray.muttrc
/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/sample.muttrc-compress
/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/sample.muttrc-sidebar
/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/sample.muttrc-tlr.gz
/usr/share/doc/mutt/examples/sample.muttrc.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/muttrc.5.gz
```

I went to all locations, I can't find muttrc file?
Can I create muttrc file in text editor and type in required data?
If yes, what I need to include in muttrc file (which information)?

Comment: Yes, it's a text file. Yes, you need to create it. No, we do not know what you need in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### .muttrc

The Mutt configuration file is `~/.muttrc`, i.e. the file called `.muttrc` in your home directory. It's up to you to create it and configure it. Mutt won't create it for you. With no configuration file, you just get the mail on your local machine (if you have local mail set up, which is not the case on Ubuntu by default).

Most email providers support [IMAPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) to read your mailbox and manage your emails, and [SMTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) to send emails. Thus the bare minimum you need to use a remote account is to set [`smtp_url`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#smtp-url) to the correct `smtps://` URL and to navigate to a [`folder`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#folder) that is an `imaps://` URL. You will probably want a few additional settings, including:

- [Caching](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#caching).
- Set the `From:` line with [`from`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#from) and declare that same address as belonging to you with [`alternates`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#alternates).

#### Gmail

Note that for Gmail you'll need to either [set up a per-application password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) (preferred) or [enable plain IMAP access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255). What Gmail calls “less secure” is applications that use your “main” Gmail password to authenticate, as opposed to either the main password plus a second authentication factor or a per-application, non-memorable password.

Looking around I find a surprising number of incomplete tutorials. There's a lot of information in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt), as usual, but it's a bit hard to digest. I'll try to be complete here but I don't actually use Mutt for Gmail so this is untested, comments welcome. Assuming that your Gmail address is `johndoe@gmail.com` and your application password is `qwertyuiop`, your `.muttrc` should contain something like this.

```
set my_address = johndoe@gmail.com
set smtp_pass = qwertyuiop

set imap_user = $my_address
set imap_pass = $smtp_pass
set smtp_url = smtps://$imap_user@smtp.gmail.com:465/
set folder = imaps://imap.gmail.com:993
set postpones = Drafts
unset record  # Gmail does this automatically

set spoolfile = +INBOX
mailboxes +INBOX

set from = $my_address
alternates $my_address

set message_cachedir = ~/.cache/mutt
set header_cache = $message_cachedir
```

If you don't want to keep your password in your configuration file, see [Mutt: how to safely store password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/mutt-how-to-safely-store-password)

#### Accessing multiple accounts

Mutt is a bit awkward when it comes to having multiple accounts. The way it works is, you put all the commands to configure each account in hooks. When you switch from one account to another, Mutt runs the hook commands. The SMTP and IMAP configuration commands go in the [`account-hook`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#account-hook) while the rest (`record`, `from`, …) go into [`folder-hook`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#folder-hook). The `alternates` and `mailboxes` settings are a list that should contain one entry per account.

Alternatively, use a separate configuration file for each account. It's less convenient but simpler.

Alternatively, use [OfflineIMAP](http://www.offlineimap.org/) to retrieve email from all your accounts, and use Mutt purely locally (except for sending).

Comment: Why is mutt designed to keep a password in txt file?

Comment: @EPo Presumably, because it keeps all of its configuration in a text file. Where else? Text files are standard and work everywhere. Password managers each have their own interface. And mutt *does* support passwords in a password manager via the `source` command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/mutt-how-to-safely-store-password

Comment: I guess there where some design tradeoffs at the time of making - [Mutt manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt#Passwords_management) itself reminds _writing your password in .muttrc is a security risk_. For git for example I'm forced to use a [credential manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), it looks a more secure default option.

Comment: Gilles, what is the `unset record` for in Mutt? Is it to disable the record var? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53060012/1705829) set record='/dev/null' is used for not storing emails. Another one: Can I omit 'alternates' if I have one account?

Comment: I got 2 errors with the script: 1) Error in /home/.muttrc, line 8: postpones: unknown variable, source: errors in /home/.muttrc
2) SASL authentication failed

Comment: ok, my first question is solved, see Arch Wiki -> Mutt: Gmail automatically saves sent e-mail to +[Gmail]/Sent, so we do not want duplicates.

unset record