# Use Mutt with Google Organization with Active Directory login

Tags: email, mutt, google

I'd like to try to connect my `mutt` email client to my Google account. However, this account is managed (G Suite) and we login via what looks like Active Directory. I'd like to connect `mutt` to this account, but I suspect it is failing because of one of two things (or both):

- Login fails because I didn't sign in with Active Directory
- I've entered inaccurate information in my config file, due to the custom domain name our organization (G Suite) is using.

Assuming:

- My email is `foo@bar.org`,
- My password (from logging in via Active Directory) is `aBcD1234`,

my configuration file looks like this:

```
# ~/.muttrc
# ~~~~~~~~~
set from = "foo@bar.org"
set realname = "Foo Barrington"

set smtp_url = "smtps://foo@bar.org"
set smtp_pass = "aBcD1234"
set record = ""

set imap_user = "foo@bar.org"
set imap_pass = "aBcD1234"

set folder = imaps://imap.gmail.com
set spoolfile = +INBOX
set record "+[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set postponed = "+[Gmail]/drafts"
```

My question is: is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

I used the guide provided on the Mutt website. Like all good documentation, I cannot find it, but I will continue to look for it. Please do not hesitate to ask clarifying questions.

:D

EDIT: ah darn, forgot password fields

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understand Your company has some IDaaS provider for authentication. The best You can do is to use OAuth2. Maybe it could work also with Google application specific passwords, but it needs to be enabled in G Suite by administrators. Also Google started to sunset all other options then OAuth2 soon [link](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html).

Fortunately mutt and neomutt has OAuth2 support - see [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#oauth) or [neomutt](https://neomutt.org/guide/optionalfeatures.html#6-%C2%A0oauthbearer-support) docs. The steps are the same, configuration should be also the same.

- Download [oauth2.py](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/python/oauth2.py) script from google/gmail-oauth2-tools repo, and make it executable
- Create credentials
- Generate refresh token

Finally put it all together in configuration.

```
set from = "foo@bar.org"
set realname = "Foo Barrington"

set smtp_url = "smtps://foo@bar.org@gmail.com"
set smtp_authenticators = "oauthbearer"
set smtp_oauth_refresh_command = "/path/to/oauth2.py --quiet \
  --user=foo@bar.org \
  --client_id=CLIENT_ID \
  --client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET \
  --refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN"

set smtp_authenticators = $smtp_authenticators
set imap_oauth_refresh_command = $smtp_oauth_refresh_command 

set folder = "imaps://foo@bar.org@imap.gmail.com:993/"
set spoolfile = +INBOX
set record "+[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set postponed = "+[Gmail]/drafts"
set record = ""
```

Don't forget to change:

- all occurrences of *foo@bar.org* to Your e-mail address,
- **/path/to/oauth2.py** to path where keep it,
- **CLIENT_ID**, **CLIENT_SECRET** and **REFRESH_TOKEN** with values you got while you were *Creating credentials* and *Generating refresh token* before - the steps from the mutt/neomutt docs.

Also keep your credentials and refreshtoken safe. Use some password manager and retrieve the passwords from there when starting mutt. See [Mutt: how to safely store password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20570/85046)