# Neomutt: add gmail account using password manager (KeepassXC)

Tags: email, authentication, mutt, gmail, keepassx

I installed **neomutt** recently I am not able to add my gmail account to it.
How can I authenticate in **neomutt** as gmail client without writing password in
config files as plain text ? I am using **KeepassXC** and I hope i is possible authenticate this way.

I configured my account file like this:

*~/.config/neomutt/account.gmail*

```bsh
set from = myemail@gmail.com

set spoolfile = ~/Mail/Gmail/INBOX
set record = ~/Mail/Gmail/Sent
set trash = ~/Mail/Gmail/Trash
set postponed = ~/Mail/Gmail/Drafts
set header_cache = ~/Mail/Gmail/Cache

set sendmail = "msmtp -a gmail"
```

How can I authenticate my self in **neomutt** using **keepassxc** ?

---

EDIT: I have found out how to send password in plaintext to stdout from keepasscx-cli [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638394/keepassxc-cli-send-password-to-stdout/638397#638397). How can i use that to authenticate to neomutt ?

Comment: Do answers below this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20570/85046 answer your question? There's several examples how to safely get password into mutt/neomutt without storing it in plaintext. Just change command to suite your needs with `keepassxc-cli`

Comment: @JakubJindra I have edited my question. Does it help ?

Comment: The answer is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20572/85046

just put your command in backticks and it will eval the output into neomutt variable value.