# KeepassXC-cli: Send password to stdout

Tags: password, mutt, stdout, stdin, keepassx

I would like to authenticate to neomutt using keepassxc. I could not find a way to send password to neomutt's stdin. How can i do that ?

I imagine something like this:

```bsh
keepassxc-cli exportpass mydatabase.kdbx  mymail@gmail.com
```

end output would be the password it self. How can I achieve this ?

EDIT: I have found out out `keepassxc-cli  show Database.kdbx accounts.google.com`. But it does not show password. Instead it returns `PROTECTED`.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to use the `-s` (`--show-protected`) and `-a` (`--attributes`) flags as follows:

```
keepassxc-cli show -sa password database entry
```

`-s` will display the password instead of `PROTECTED` , and `-a password` will output *only* the password.

Comment: Yes, this is much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```bsh
keepassxc-cli show -s Database.kdbx entryName | sed -n 3p | cut -c11-
```

Comment: `export MYSECRETENV=$(keepassxc-cli show -q -s -a password vault.kdbx -y 2:85798674 /path/to/your/Secret\ Name)` This will silent the prompt and put the password in the ENV variable. This example also uses YubiKey, `-a password` is the name of the built-in attribute named "password". I also showed whitespace escape in `Secret\ Name`.